# Lock user account for 30 mins after 3 attempts and fully lock after 6?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership

How can I lock a user account for 30 mins if 3 successful attempts are made but also have it so that if 6 attempts are made the account is locked requiring admin unlock.

So in my web config I have:

```
maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="6"
```

That works fine in that if 6 invalid attempts are made in the aspnetdb table I can see that IsLockedOut gets set to true.  However i am trying to build on that so that if a User enters wrong details 3 times I do the following:

```
                    if (user.FailedPasswordAttemptCount > 3)
                    {
                        memberUser.IsApproved = false;

                        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Your account has been locked out for 30 minutes.  Please retry after this time has elasped.  Note 3 further wrong entries " +
                        "will result in your account being locked requiring Admin reset");

                        membershipService.UpdateUser(memberUser);

                    }
```

So user is a view I have created in my db where I get the value from the aspnetdb table and if greater than 3 attempts I set isApproved property on aspnet db table to false.

further up in my login method I have the following:

```
            if (memberUser.IsApproved == false)
            {

                DateTime PasswordFailedTime = user.FailedPasswordAttemptWindowStart.AddMinutes(30);
                DateTime CurrentTime = DateTime.UtcNow;

                if (CurrentTime > PasswordFailedTime)
                {
                   memberUser.IsApproved = true;
                   membershipService.UpdateUser(memberUser);
                }

            }
```

So if 30 mins have passed since the failure time re-approve the account.  The problem is that even though I say on screen wait for 30 mins - if a user tried again 3 times i want to lock the account.  But becasue I assume the IsApproved property is false the FailedPasswordAttemptCount never gets incremented so I never get to the 6 value that locks the account and displays the message saying your account is locked required admin unlock.